# How does the voltage division on this work?

Tags: voltage-divider

[image]

How does the voltage division of this work? I understanding other types using KVL, but this I am just lost. Im not comfortable blindly taking the answer and would like to know. Or is the answer just flat out wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in this particular circuit, we can see that the overall voltage across the RC branch of the circuit containing V<sub>φ</sub> is equal to V<sub>o</sub>. Given this fact, we can then use the impedances of the resistor and the capacitor to determine V<sub>φ</sub>. The voltage division rule for two series impedances Z<sub>1</sub> and Z<sub>2</sub> (where Z<sub>2</sub> is tied to ground) is given by: $$ V_o = \frac{Z_2}{Z_1+Z_2}V_{source}  $$If this is true, we can identify both the bottommost wire in the diagram as ground and the capacitor as Z<sub>2</sub> in our voltage divider equation (which, consequently, leaves the resistor as Z<sub>1</sub>). Given this information, the equation for V<sub>φ</sub> becomes: $$ V_{\phi} = \frac{\frac{10^4}{s}}{50+\frac{10^4}{s}}V_o $$ From here, we can multiply this equation by 1,which is the same as multiplying both top and bottom by s, which transforms the equation into: $$ V_\phi = \frac{10^4}{50s+10^4}V_o $$ Hope this was helpful!

Comment: So for this particular question there is no way to derive it from the ground up?

Comment: Do you mean the voltage divider rule?

Comment: yes. Normally, if someone uses the voltage divider rule I can come to the same conclusion using nodal analysis but in this case Im not having any luck.

Comment: So are you asking to derive the voltage divider rule or apply it to this specific context?

Comment: derive it, but in the context of this problem.

Comment: Okay, that is what I did above. What parts about that do you not understand (this message is not intended to convey a harsh tone by the way)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50066/discussion-between-user132849-and-mattjd).